# Bash: Create folders from file name

Tags: bash, macos, filesystems

I have a folder with a number of .png files, for example:

```
Jeff Smith 1.png
Jeff Donald 1.png
Jeff Donald 2.png
Jeff Smith 2.png
Jeff Roberts.png
Kyle Reds.png
Kyle Reds 1.png
Kyle Blues 1.png
Kyle Blues 2.png
Kyle Person.png
etc 
etc
```

How would I write a bash script that could create a folder for every unique name.

For the example above, we would get folders:

```
Jeff Smith
Jeff Donald
Kyle Reds
Kyle Blues
Kyle Person 
etc
```

I am brand new to bash (and coding in general) - hoping to get some help on this

Thanks

Comment: `for i in *.png; do mkdir -p "$(basename "$i" .png)"; done`

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. List files in the directory removing the enumeration and extension suffix with `sed` and assign it to a variable

```
prefixes_png=$(ls | sed -r 's/\s?[0-9]*\.\w+$//')
```

2. Sort the lines and remove duplicate rows

```
unique_prefixes=$(echo "$prefixes_png" | sort -u)
```

3. Iterate through the names creating a matching directory for each one

```
echo "$unique_prefixes" | while read prefix
do
   mkdir "$prefix"
done
```

Comment: Using the GNU `ls -Q` option is (usually) okay, but in general you shouldn't try to [parse the output from ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In addition, the OP is on macOS; your sed pattern won't work on BSD sed, and you can't be sure the OP has installed GNU sed (usually as gsed). Other than that, your solution certainly works with the OP's provided inputs, so kudos for that.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0):

### Standard Utilities or Pure Bash: You Make the Call!

If you don't need a pure Bash solution, you could use standard utilities like find, sed, and sort. For example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.png |
    sed 's!^\./!!; s/[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*\.[Pp][Nn][Gg]//' |
    sort -u |
    xargs -I{} mkdir "{}"
```

This works well, is very compact, and is relatively easy to understand if you can get past the regular expression in sed. You could also do it in pure Bash with some [shell options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html), an [associative array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html), and some [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). For example:

```
# make shell globs case insensitive
shopt -s nocaseglob

# turn on extended globs for more advanced pattern matching
shopt -s extglob

# associative array ensures names (keys) are unique
declare -A names

# create empty key for each name extracted from a filename
for file in *.png; do
    names["${file%%*([[:space:]])*([[:digit:]]).png}"]=
done 

# create a directory for each key in the array
for name in "${!names[@]}"; do
    mkdir "$name"
done

# revert shell options
shopt -u extglob
shopt -u nocaseglob
```

Both solutions will work. The standard utilities will probably be faster and (IMHO) easier to tweak, while the Bash-only version avoids the need to call any external commands. Which one is best for your use case is entirely up to you!